# Connecting Access front end to SQL server back end connectivity problems

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an Access database which I migrated from Access to SQl SERVER 2008 R2.  I have enabled TCP/IP connections on the database and I can connect across the network to the database via SSMS.  However, when I try to use the linked table manager in Access, I get the Server does not exist or Access is denied error message.
I am using the same username and password in the Access Linked table manager that I connect with on SSMS.  I don't have any idea where else to go with this.  Anyone?

Comment: Have you tested the ODBC DSN for the connection you intend to use? You can to that via `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC)` by selecting the DSN, clicking the "Configure..." button, following the wizard through the steps, then clicking the "Test Data Source..." button on the final dialog.

Comment: We should also ask:  you have set up an ODBC DSN, right?  You know that Access won't know where to find the SQL Server instance unless you do that?

Comment: It is in setting up the DSN that I have the issue.  So, no, the DSN is not set up correctly!  But I don't know what could be wrong.